# Conjoin function made in functional style

Tags: python, functional-programming

Recently, reading Python ["Functional Programming HOWTO"](http://docs.python.org/howto/functional.html), I came across a mentioned there `test_generators.py` standard module, where I found the following generator:

```
# conjoin is a simple backtracking generator, named in honor of Icon's
# "conjunction" control structure.  Pass a list of no-argument functions
# that return iterable objects.  Easiest to explain by example:  assume the
# function list [x, y, z] is passed.  Then conjoin acts like:
#
# def g():
#     values = [None] * 3
#     for values[0] in x():
#         for values[1] in y():
#             for values[2] in z():
#                 yield values
#
# So some 3-lists of values *may* be generated, each time we successfully
# get into the innermost loop.  If an iterator fails (is exhausted) before
# then, it "backtracks" to get the next value from the nearest enclosing
# iterator (the one "to the left"), and starts all over again at the next
# slot (pumps a fresh iterator).  Of course this is most useful when the
# iterators have side-effects, so that which values *can* be generated at
# each slot depend on the values iterated at previous slots.

def simple_conjoin(gs):

    values = [None] * len(gs)

    def gen(i):
        if i >= len(gs):
            yield values
        else:
            for values[i] in gs[i]():
                for x in gen(i+1):
                    yield x

    for x in gen(0):
        yield x
```

It took me a while to understand how it works. It uses a mutable list `values` to store the yielded results of the iterators, and the N+1 iterator return the `values`, which passes through the whole chain of the iterators.

As I stumbled into this code while reading about functional programming, I started thinking if it was possible to rewrite this conjoin generator using functional programming (using functions from the [`itertools` module](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html)).
There are a lot of routines written in functional style (just glance at the end of [this](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#recipes) article in the Recipes section).

But, unfortunately, I haven't found any solution.

So, is it possible to write this conjoin generator using functional programming just using the [`itertools` module](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html)?

Thanks

Comment: It seems counter-intuitive to mix a functional style with the expectation of side effects.  If the functions were pure, each one would only need to be called once.

@Ionuț:  It's not like `map` or `zip`.  It's closer to a cartesian product, but there's a twist of function application mixed in for flavor.

Comment: Either you want lazy, functional programming with no side-effects, in which case you want `itertools.product`, or you want side-effects, in which case you have to do it yourself. You can't have both.

Comment: So, if I understand right, they made that quite complicated code with using the mutable `values` list just to be able to access the values generated by all enclosing iterators to the left. And if we don't need any side-effects, we can use `itertools.product` to get the same functionality.

Comment: @revursive, yes, you're right. I noticed it after submitting the comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This seems to work, and it's still lazy:

```
def conjoin(gs):
    return [()] if not gs else (
        (val,) + suffix for val in gs[0]() for suffix in conjoin(gs[1:])
    )

def range3():
    return range(3)

print list(conjoin([range3, range3]))
```

Output:

```
[(0, 0), (0, 1), (0, 2), (1, 0), (1, 1), (1, 2), (2, 0), (2, 1), (2, 2)]
```

Example usage to show mutable state:

```
x = ""
def mutablerange():
    global x
    x += "x"
    return [x + str(i) for i in range(3)]

print list(conjoin([range3, mutablerange]))
```

Output:  (watch the increasing number of 'x's)

```
[(0, 'x0'), (0, 'x1'), (0, 'x2'), (1, 'xx0'), (1, 'xx1'), (1, 'xx2'), (2, 'xxx0'), (2, 'xxx1'), (2, 'xxx2')]
```

And if we use `itertools.product`:

```
x = ""
print list(itertools.product(range3(), mutablerange()))
```

the result is the following:

```
[(0, 'x0'), (0, 'x1'), (0, 'x2'), (1, 'x0'), (1, 'x1'), (1, 'x2'), (2, 'x0'), (2, 'x1'), (2, 'x2')]
```

So, one clearly see, that `itertools.product` caches the values returned by the iterator.

Comment: Yeah. Thanks. But it's not really functinal-style. @katrielalex in the comments mentioned that the same functionality can be achieved by using `itertools.product` function.

Comment: How is it not functional?  `itertools.product` is different because it doesn't do the function application.  It works with lists of values.  My implementation re-applies the functions so that any side-effects will happen correctly, per your definition of conjoin.  `product` does not.

Comment: Why can't we call `itertools.product` in the following way: `itertools.product(gs1(),gs2(),...)` ?

Comment: @ovgolovin:  It was specified that conjoin had to re-apply each function each time it was iterated over so that side effects could happen.  Both of your proposals will call them only once.

Comment: I must admit that I at first didn't understand that the conjoint function that I mentioned in the question-post is remarkable in that it can use the data of the enclosing generators. And then @ katrielalex wrote about `itertools.product` and I remembered that it does the same thing that the simple_conjoin. I couldn't think of anything because at first I was kind of shoked with the complexity of the simple_conjoin (all those uses of the mutable `values` and lack of understanding how the data is passed through all those nested generators).

Comment: The mutability of `values` isn't the core thing. It's that the functions change some other thing (anything), that stays changed between times they are run, so that their next run can be influenced by their previous run. This is what makes it impossible to create a true functional implementation that is also useful (recursive's is one or the other, not both at the same time) -- the functions have to have side effects (not be pure) in order to be useful with `simple_conjoin`. Without side effects, it's just a cartesian product, as others have mentioned.

Comment: @recursive And how can the iterators access the values generated by all the enclosing generators? In the `simple_conjoin` they are all stored in `values`. And were are they stored in this code?

Comment: @agf And why can't one of the iterators change anything while it's called by `itertools.product`?

Comment: @ovgolovin: The `values` variable is local to the function, and can't be modified by anything else.  In my example, `range3` could have some state.

Comment: @ovgolovin: The functions can't change anything with product because they're only called once each.

Comment: With `itertools.product`, each function is only iterated over once. With `simple_conjoin`, how many times each inner loop happens depends on when the outer loops are exhausted, so the functions may be iterated over many time. Sure, you could use functions with side effects with `itertools.product`, but they would still only be iterated over once, so you can't get i.e. `(0, 0), (0, 1), (1, 10), (5, 11)`, because the values are reused, so if you get `0` then `1` from the 2nd iterator, you will always have `0` or `1` in the 2nd column.

Comment: So the answer, as I said in my post, is you can't have a useful `simple_conjoin` that is also functional, because it is only it's side effects that make it special.

Comment: @ovgolovin, the weird `for values[0] in x():` thing is a red herring -- it's just a clever accumulator. The difference between this and `itertools.product` is that `itertools.product` accepts _generators_ and _caches_ values that will be used multiple times, while `conjoin` accepts _generator functions_ which it re-calls instead of using cached values.

Comment: Please, can you write an answer which shows the hallmark of simple_conjoin function with using side-effects. Just to show what it can do in comparison with `itertools.product` (which is perfectly in functional style but which lacks of that side-effects). I'm asking because we have written a lot of information here in the comments and I can't make any answer "accepted" (since all the information is scattered all over the comments) and I can't answer my own questions since I don't have enough rep. (and I can't think up any example with those side-effects). Thanks!

Comment: @ovgolovin: I've added a usage example which shows the use of side effects.

Comment: @agf In fact, a [pure Python equivalent of `itertools.product` code](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) shows that each function iterates over many times (not once as you write above). That is the code for it: `result = [x+[y] for x in result for y in pool]` (**for y in pool**). But that iterator happens to be created only once from the generator (at the very beginning of `product` function). So, there is no real caching.

Comment: Yes, I should have said the values are "generated once", rather than "iterated over once". The example I gave is still valid, and the effect is the same -- without side effects, `simple_conjoin` is just a Cartesian product; with side effects, it's not purely functional. So the answer to your question is still that you can't write `simple_conjoin` in functional programming, since if you do it's not really `simple_conjoin`.

Answer (score 2):

`simple_conjoin` uses the same basic building blocks -- loops, conditions, and `yield` -- as the building blocks of the `itertools` recipes. It also treats functions as data, a hallmark of functional programming.

> Of course this is most useful when the
>   iterators have side-effects, so that which values *can* be generated at
>   each slot depend on the values iterated at previous slots.

This, however, is contrary to the way functional programming works. In functional programming, each function takes input and produces output, and reacts with the rest of the program in no other way.

In `simple_conjoin`, the functions take no input, and have side effects. This is central to it's use.

So while you can certainly *write* it in functional style, it won't be useful in simple translation.

You'd need to figure out a way to write it so it operated without side effects before you could produce a truly "functional" implementation.

Note: @recursive's answer is good, but if `range3` had side effects it wouldn't be truly functional.