# Python script for zoning WWN

Tags: python

I am just learning basic python for myself - and hoping to make some simple ..and I mean simple scripts to do a few repetitive tasks

One of these is zoning WWN for Cisco switches in a SAN

Normally we would need 2 WWNs of 2 ports (ie a host =20:00:00:00:00:00:00:00 + Storgae box =50:06:01:00:00:00:00:00)
Once we have that, we make a name and add these WWN to it

```
zone name **host_Storage**
Adding member: member pwwn 50:06:01:00:00:00:00:00 (ie Storage)
Adding member: member pwwn 20:00:00:00:00:00:00:00 (ie host)
```

---

I am at the start and want to get a input of a WWN and if its either one of the 2 WWN numbers

- 2000000000000000
- 20:00:00:00:00:00:00:00

It will always give me the 2nd format,

ie 20:00:00:00:00:00:00:00

I found something that does this here:
[Inserting a character at regular intervals in a list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8346735/inserting-a-character-at-regular-intervals-in-a-list)

But would like to get this working in a script

This works---

```
s = '10000000c9abcdef'
':'.join(a + b for a, b in zip(*[iter(s)]*2))

'10:00:00:00:c9:ab:cd:ef'
```

This does not work (when trying to create a type of script) --

```
wwn = (input('Enter the WWN or q to quit- ')) 
':'.join(a + b for a, b in zip(*[iter(wwn)]*2))
```

Comment: Seems to work fine for me, what error are you getting (if any) and what version of Python are you running (I am assuming 3+ from the input method)? Only potential problem I see is if you enter a number already colon delimited will still insert them.

Comment: ```C:\Python27>www.py
    ```Enter the WWN or q to quit- 10000000c9abcdef
    ```Traceback (most recent call last):
    ```File "C:\Python27\www.py", line 3, in <module>
    wwn = (input('Enter the WWN or q to quit- '))
    ```File "<string>", line 1
    ```10000000c9abcdef
                   ^
   ```SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing

Comment: Hi fredtantini -- tried to pste code -- but does not look great above :)

Comment: I will try and change again and get it a bit better--one thing to note is I am not using 3+ at present..Cheers again

Comment: If you're using python 2.7 then you need to replace `input()` with `raw_input()` as the former is only used in Python 3+, whereas in Python 2+ is tries to eval the input as a variable.

Comment: Thanks iChar..   
Used the following ..

wwn = (raw_input('Enter the WWN or q to quit- ')) 
':'.join(a + b for a, b in zip(*[iter(wwn)]*2)) 
print wwn 
==============================
And the respoonse was this 
==============================
C:\Python27>www.py 
Enter the WWN or q to quit- 10000000c9abcdef
10000000c9abcdef 


It did not come back with correct formart Im afraid

Comment: :)...cheers for the first bit iChar...modified it a bit more and looks to be working..will mess more with it and expand but you got me started..Cheers again...This is the code that is working and its output====================================================================wwn = (raw_input('Enter the WWN or q to quit- ')) 
wwnadded =':'.join(a + b for a, b in zip(*[iter(wwn)]*2))
print wwnadded====================================================================C:\Python27>www.py
Enter the WWN or q to quit- 2000000000000000
20:00:00:00:00:00:00:00==================

Answer (score 0):

You Can use regex to achieve the same:

```
import re
wwn="5006010000000000"
':'.join(re.findall('..', wwn))

'50:06:01:00:00:00:00:00'
```