# Generating combinations of a string (not permutations)

Tags: python, algorithm, combinations

I've tried to implement the algorithm in "Programming Interviews Exposed" in Python, as below, but it doesn't seem to work (page 99 on the 2nd Edition):

The idea is to generate all combinations (not permutations) of a string, such that if you input "wxyz" you would get "w, wx, wxy, wxyz, wxz, wy, wyz, wz....  " etc. if wz is displayed then zw is not valid.

```
def doCombine(strng, out, length, level, start):
    for i in range(start, length):
        out.append(strng[i])
        print out
        if (i < length - 1):
            doCombine(strng, out, length, level +1, i + 1)
        out = out[:-1]

x = list()
target = "wxyz"
print doCombine(target, x, len(target), 0, 0)
```

What could be amiss here? I get relatively garbage output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your current code, try changing the line `out = out[:-1]` to `del out[-1]`.  Both of those result in `out` having the last item removed, but in your current code `out` is reassigned instead of using the same list.  This results in characters never being removed from the original list, which will obviously mess with the output pretty significantly.

After making that change, here is the output:

```
>>> print doCombine(target, x, len(target), 0, 0)
['w']
['w', 'x']
['w', 'x', 'y']
['w', 'x', 'y', 'z']
['w', 'x', 'z']
['w', 'y']
['w', 'y', 'z']
['w', 'z']
['x']
['x', 'y']
['x', 'y', 'z']
['x', 'z']
['y']
['y', 'z']
['z']
None
```

Comment: Awesome! I'll have to wrap my head around that difference, but thanks!

Comment: @Rio - Glad this helped, as for wrapping your head around the difference, your original code was equivalent to completely taking out the line that removed characters from the list.  Since `out` is mutable you can modify it in `doCombine`, but if you reassign `out` to a new value the caller's version of `out` will be unchanged.

Comment: Depending on your sense of aesthetics, `out.pop()` may be a slightly prettier alternative to `del out[-1]`.

Comment: Some people might fret over the _popped_ value never being assigned anywhere. But it is prettier I admit.

Answer (score 2):

See the combinations() function from the [itertools](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations) module.

Comment: Can one do it without itertools? The algorithmic part is what interests me, and the PIE book explains it pretty nicely. I just don't quite get why it wouldn't work...

Comment: Generally, yes. Just have a look at the source code in the link I gave. What you want to achieve surely cannot happen with the code you provided. It seems to do another thing.

Comment: @hymloth - The code Rio provided is actually very close to a working solution, see my answer.

Comment: @Rio FWIW, the documentation for the itertools module includes pure python equivalents for each tool -- the algorithms are in plain sight :-)

Answer (score 1):

I've rewritten this combine function using a recursive generator. The output is an iterator.

```
def combine(s):
    length = len(s)
    def gen(start, prepending=[]): #recursive generator
        if start == length-1:
            yield prepending + [s[start]]
        else:
            for i in range(start,length):
                current = prepending + [s[i]] #save the current list for reusing
                yield current
                for els in gen(i+1,current):
                    yield els
    for v in gen(0):
        yield v

s = "wxyz"
for v in combine(s):
    print(v)
```

It's not very easy to understand at once.

The same technique is used in conjoin generator: [Conjoin function made in functional style](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7093121/conjoin-function-made-in-functional-style).

Also, I refactored your function a bit while trying to understand how it works.
I'll put it here for those who may be interested to ease their understanding.

```
def combine(s):
    out = []
    length = len(s)
    def loc(start):
        for i in range(start, length):
            out.append(s[i])
            print out
            if (i < length-1):
                loc(i+1)
            del out[-1]
    loc(0)
```

---

**I made some efficiency calculations.**

The code which uses appendings and deletions from `out` (a slightly modified code of the original poster to work as a generator) is a bit faster than the code I provided in this answer (I think it's because I used `prepending + [s[i]]` on each iteration which creates a new list in memory. Appendings and deletions on the same list turn out to be faster).

Details here:
https://ideone.com/V3WIM

Answer (score 0):

The line `out.append(strng[i])` does not match the described algorithm.  You don't want to append, you want to set out[level] = strng[i]

Comment: That's true, but I had approximated the character array as a simple array, where we could just join at the end. Thanks for the heads up though!